# How to calculate the mean of few columns and put the result in new column?

Tags: r

There are few columns including the length of people in my data table. I would like to calculate the mean of all of the length and put the result in the new column.

data:

```
         Length1   Length2   Length3   Length4
Markus     172       179       192       186

Mark       175       181       184       183

Lionel     177       188       183       184
```

Comment: are you asking for few rows or few columns ?

Comment: few columns.. my mistake. I want to calculate the mean of Markus' length etc.

Answer (score 0):

Let’s try with that:

```
data$mean_length <- rowMeans(data, select = c("Length1", "Length2", " Length3", " Length4")), na.rm = TRUE)
```

It’s propably not the most “effective” way to do it but for sure it works..

Comment: why do you need the `subset`?  `data$mean_length <- rowMeans(data)` should be plenty...

Comment: I changed it as you suggested. Thanks.